# How to detach Firebase project from organisation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, google-cloud-console

I'm trying to detach a personal Firebase project from my organisation that was wrongfully attached during creation. This seems impossible. In the IAM & admin console there's a tooltip near the organisation section: `Projects can't be detached from their organization`.

As an alternative, can I somehow duplicate this project, and then remove the source while keeping my custom domains connected?